# Pros/Cons of strong-named/signed assemblies

Tags: .net, assembly-signing

We have a solution with many projects in it (probably 20 or more). Recently we've made some changes that require a couple of those assemblies to be callable from COM, which means we need to strong-name them. Those assemblies reference others in our project, which means they need to be strong-named as well. They also have InternalsVisibleTo attributes, so the assemblies that are granted that must also be strong-named.

Rather than hunt-and-peck trying to find just which assemblies need signing/strong-naming, I recommended we simply strong-name them all. This has put a couple of people in a tizzy about risk. I'm arguing that there is no risk, but they want pros and cons of signing assemblies. The only things I've been able to come up with are:

Pros

- It's a requirement to call the
  assembly from COM
- It would allow us
  to put the assemblies in the GAC (we
  don't do that now)
- It prevents
  tampering (we host the application,
  it's not installed on client sites,
  so not that big an issue)

Cons

- It requires that every assembly we use in the future be signed

I have two specific questions:

1. Would you say, in general, it's a good idea to sign/strong-name assemblies?
2. Can you think of any other pros or cons?

Comment: Where does the idea that everything must now be signed come from? It's unsigned assemblies that are viral: you can't reference a unsigned assembly from a signed assembly. You can do the opposite though. The ones that *must* be signed are due to the reasons you outlined in the first paragraph.

Comment: BTW: It doesn't stop tampering. You can strip off the SN, and change the referencing assemblies, and you're good to go. I did this as a proof-of-concept on some commercial software using Reflector and Reflexil

Comment: @David: and you can even you do it with ilasm and ildasm alone. @Future David: thanks, I switched the order of signed/unsigned.

Comment: @Martino I think you go that last part muddled up - you can't reference an unsigned assembly from a signed assembly, but you can reference a signed assembly from an unsigned assembly.

Comment: I never said everything in our solution _had_ to be signed. My point was that rather than hunting and pecking to figure out which ones had to be signed it would be simpler to just sign them all. It would also avoid problems in the future where a developer set a reference from a signed project to an unsigned project and suddenly the solution won't compile because now we have to sign that newly referenced project and hunt down all the things _it_ references to make sure _they_ are signed.

Answer (score 5):

Your single con is bogus. It's actually a pro.

> Unsigned assemblies can be used *exclusively* by unsigned assemblies. Signed assemblies can be used by *both* signed assemblies and unsigned assemblies.

Comment: I happen to think it's a pro as well, but being objective about it, it does mean that any software we bring into the organization from now own (commercial, open source, shareware, whatever) must provide a signed version _or_ we must be able to build a signed version with our own snk. I think from the perspective of the business that could be considered a con.

Comment: @Craig: That's a valid point. I was thinking about an ideal situation with responsible providers :(. It's sad that not everyone that makes reusable software signs what they put out without even thinking twice about it: it's the only way to make all your clients happy.

Answer (score 4):

"It's a requirement to call the assembly from COM"

You dont need to sign an assembly to make it a COM Component. I implemented a lot of COM-server without signing the assembly.

some more Cons:

- you cant update an assembly with a new version without replacing all other assemblies requiring it => no shared components easily
- can't use non signed third party components (many Free/OpenSource)
- signed assemblies in the GAC are not validated, someone evil can alter/replace your signed assembly with anything and your programs happily accept this anything [link](http://ianpicknell.blogspot.com/2010/02/faking-strong-name.html)

Comment: "you cant update an assembly with a new version without replacing all other assemblies requiring it => no shared components easily" Not true. You have to add a line to your config for the binding redirect. It may be a con still, but not as catastrophic.

Comment: you have to add it to every application which uses the component. Not easy if you have app->module->component and you update the component then app has to add the redirect for component which it doesn't even know about. A common scenario for utility dlls incorporated in modules

Comment: "you cant update an assembly with a new version without replacing all other assemblies requiring it" you ought to tell that to Microsoft, because they've been doing that for a long time now.

Comment: @Voo You can only change the file if it has the same version and public key. I "enjoyed" the fun of evolving libraries with the same version because dependend assemblies would not load it anymore. MS does only ship internal bug fixes this way.

Comment: and altering mashine.config to redirect to newer versions asks for trouble.

Comment: @Firo Quite true. Now just think about the fact that a program compiled against System.dll of .NET 4.0 will run perfectly fine on .NET 4.6. The "trick" is to only update your assembly version if you introduce breaking changes, you can still update the file version to be able to distinguish different versions. Voila, you can create new versions without trouble just as without signing and you have to added benefit of being able to make sure that someone doesn't use an actually binary incompatible new release.

Comment: You can decide with unsigned assemblies to take specific or nonspecific versions too. With signed you can only use specific versions. If only the fileversion is ever incremeneted for additions but not breaking changes its the same problem i had, MethodNotFoundException at runtime.

Comment: @Firo The reason to update a assembly version is to make sure an incompatible version of the dll leads to errors immediately instead of unexpected somewhere down the line with potential data corruption issues. There are also backwards incompatible changes that are binary compatible (changing the meaning of a parameter for example) which is impossible to catch with unsigned assemblies. So all in all it's wrong that you cannot release new versions (the .NET framework demonstrates that nicely) and there are possible additional features you can use if you want to.

Comment: Also your "evil attacker link" requires the attacker to already have admin rights. If the first step of your evil exploit requires acquiring admin rights, that's not an exploit, that's social engineering and there's really no technical solution to that.

Comment: Assuming Desktop-Apps: altering dlls in the program folder does require admin rights too. No difference between signed and unsigned dlls in terms of security.

Answer (score 3):

- It's a requirement of ClickOnce that your assemblies are signed
- A lot of opensource projects do not distribute signed assemblies, and are often non-trivial to compile with your own SNK

Comment: Combined into 1 answer. Thanks to the community feedback on this.

Comment: +1 for the mention of non-signed distributions. It's a hassle when you have to install stuff just so you can run the build script of an open-source project, because the devs heard some FUD about signing assemblies and got scared.

Comment: We've considered the open source issue. Our company is reluctant to incorporate open source solutions, and the few that we do use either provided a signed assembly or were very simple to build a signed version.